# Flutter BLoC: Is using nested StreamBuilders a bad practice?

Tags: architecture, flutter, bloc

Is there a better way to expose a widget to two or more streams from different BLoCs? So far I have been using nested `StreamBuilder`'s for as many streams as I need listening to like the pasted code below. Is this a good practice?

```dart
StreamBuilder(
    stream: firstBloc.stream1,
    builder: (_, AsyncSnapshot snapshot1) {
        return StreamBuilder(
            stream: secondBloc.stream2,
            builder: (_, AsyncSnapshot snapshot2) {
                return CustomWidget(snapshot1.data, snapshot2.data);
            }
        )
    }
)
```

Using `rxdart` operators like `combineLatest2` feels clunky since at most times I do not want one of the bloc's being used to be aware of streams in another bloc.

Comment: with `ScopedModel` you can have multiple models without any problems

Comment: I am sorry but I don't understand how this would fit with the BLoC pattern. Do you mean I should use `ScopedModel` instead of BLoC in this case or do you mean I can somehow integrate the two of them together ?

Comment: see https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-app-architecture-101-vanilla-scoped-model-bloc-7eff7b2baf7e

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do otherwise using widgets. That's one of the limitations of the widget system: things tend to get pretty nested

There's one solution though: Hooks, a new feature coming from React, ported to Flutter through [flutter_hooks](https://github.com/rrousselGit/flutter_hooks) (I'm the maintainer).

The end result becomes this:

```
final snapshot1 = useStream(firstBloc.stream1);
final snapshot2 = useStream(secondBloc.stream2);

return CustomWidget(snapshot1.data, snapshot2.data);
```

This behaves exactly like two nested `StreamBuilder`, but everything is done within the same without and without nesting.

Answer (score 0):

You can put them in a MultiBlocProvider at the top of the app.