# Why does this "StreamBuilder" use data from a previously closed stream?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this very simple Flutter app:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "Debug",
      initialRoute: "/",
      routes: {
        "/": (context) => MainPage(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

With `MainPage` being:

```dart
class MainPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final _rebuilder = StreamController<void>.broadcast();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    debugPrint("Initializing the app main page");
    var isButtonPressed = StreamController<bool>.broadcast();

    return StreamBuilder<void>(
      stream: _rebuilder.stream,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        debugPrint("Rebuilding (stream = ${isButtonPressed.stream.hashCode})");
        return StreamBuilder<bool>(
          stream: isButtonPressed.stream,
          initialData: false,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            var pressed = snapshot.data;
            debugPrint("Button state: $pressed (stream = ${isButtonPressed.stream.hashCode})");
            return RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                debugPrint("Closing and rebuilding (stream = ${isButtonPressed.stream.hashCode})");
                isButtonPressed.sink.add(true);
                isButtonPressed.close();
                isButtonPressed = StreamController<bool>.broadcast();
                _rebuilder.sink.add(null);
              },
              child: Text("Pressed: $pressed"),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

It uses two [`StreamController`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/StreamController-class.html): the `_rebuilder` is used to **generate a new button**, and the `isButtonPressed` is used to **update the existing button**.

As you see, when the button is pressed, I update it through the stream's sink, then close the stream, and finally ask for a new button to be created.

However, it looks like when the button's [`StreamBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html) is created a second time, it is not initialized using the `initialData: false`, because `pressed == true` although `stream.hashCode` is different.

```
I/flutter ( 4207): Initializing the app main page
I/flutter ( 4207): Rebuilding (stream = 773570673)
I/flutter ( 4207): Button state: false (stream = 773570673)
I/flutter ( 4207): Closing and rebuilding (stream = 773570673)
I/flutter ( 4207): Rebuilding (stream = 786124862)
I/flutter ( 4207): Button state: true (stream = 786124862)
```

I don't understand. I expected the new stream to be empty, and hence the button's state to be `false`. Why isn't it the case?

Comment: why do you use two (nested) `StreamBuilder`s? instead you should use some `Stream` API (like `asyncExpand()`) or `rxdart` (like `*Map()`) methods

Comment: @pskink Why not? I have done some research and the use of nested `StreamBuilder` [does not seem to be prohibited](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54841847/2291710). Of course, this is a very contrived example, I tried to make a minimum reproducible example. I would like to understand why it's behaving this way before adding another level abstraction.

Comment: @pskink At the risk of repeating myself: this is an intentionally contrived example...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is not in the Streams. Streambuilder itself also widget that uses state methods. So, you should add key property to Streambuilder and that's it. Code below.

```
class MainPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final _rebuilder = StreamController<void>.broadcast();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    debugPrint("Initializing the app main page");
    var isButtonPressed = StreamController<bool>.broadcast();

    return StreamBuilder<void>(
      stream: _rebuilder.stream,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        debugPrint("Rebuilding (stream = ${isButtonPressed.stream.hashCode})");
        return StreamBuilder<bool>(
          key: UniqueKey(),
          stream: isButtonPressed.stream,
          initialData: false,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            var pressed = snapshot.data;
            debugPrint(
                "Button state: $pressed (stream = ${isButtonPressed.stream.hashCode})");
            return RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                debugPrint(
                    "Closing and rebuilding (stream = ${isButtonPressed.stream.hashCode})");
                isButtonPressed.sink.add(true);
                isButtonPressed.close();
                isButtonPressed = StreamController<bool>.broadcast();
                _rebuilder.sink.add(null);
              },
              child: Text("Pressed: $pressed"),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

(Thanks to [@Delgan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2291710/delgan) for finding logical mistakes, the answer have edited.)

Comment: God, hours of headaches solved with just one new parameter! So, from what I understand, using a `key` prevent Flutter to optimize or somehow re-use the same object, which produced the unexpected result. The rendering process and interactions between Widget, Element and State is still quite a black-box to me, but it gives me the opportunity to learn a lot of new things. Also, I noted that it still work if `MainPage` is a `StatelessWidget`, adding a `key` seems to fix everything. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are right, thank you. Fixed the answer.
In real app I usually use Stateful widgets for working with Streams because of convenient dispose() method.
But for this example it is more correct to use Stateless widget.